Dirichlet integral with a decay still has the same value at high frequency.
The Dirichlet integral is: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{x} dx = \pi/2$, for any frequency $k>0$.
Now if you multiply the integrand with another decaying function, eg $e^{-x}$, then it no longer integrates to $\pi/2$ in general. But as $k \rightarrow \infty$, it again integrates to $\pi/2$, i.e.:
$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{x} e^{-x} dx = \pi/2$.
I have numerically checked that this seems to hold for any decaying function, not just $e^{-x}$.
Is that true, and is there a mathematical explanation or proof for why this happens?

If you denote by $f(x)$ a continuous "decaying function" and consider the change of variable $kx=u$ you have:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}xf(x) \mathrm dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin u}{u}kf\left(\frac uk\right)\frac{\mathrm du}k=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin u}{u}f\left(\frac uk\right)\mathrm du\to \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}f(0)\mathrm du$$
by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Oh yeah, what a succint explanation. I can visualize using the last two steps, that the function f essentially 'stretches out' in the limit of large k, so only its value at 0 ends up mattering.

The dominated convergence requires that the absolute values of the integrands are bounded above by an integrable function. This assumption is not satisfied in your solution.

Perhaps this result follows only for those functions that are bounded above by an integrable function and the dominated convergence theorem holds.

@RyszardSzwarc yes, $\frac{\sin x} x$ is not in $L^1$. Is there a way to correct this approach to use the DCT?

We have $$ \int\limits_0^\infty {\sin u\over u}f(u/k)\,du =\int\limits_0^N {\sin u\over u}f(u/k)\,du +\int\limits_N^\infty {\sin u\over u}f(u/k)\,du  $$ The first term tends to $f(0)\int\limits_0^N{\sin u\over u}\,du .$ Next we apply the second mean value theorem for integrals to get    $$ \int\limits_N^M{\sin u\over u}f(u/k)\,du  = {1\over N}f(N/k)\int\limits_N^{M'}\sin u\,du$$ for $M>N.$ Thus $$\left |\int\limits_N^M{\sin u\over u}f(u/k)\,du  \right |\le {2\over N}f(N/k)\le {2\over N}f(0)$$ As $M$ is arbitrary we obtain  $$\left |\int\limits_N^\infty {\sin u\over u}f(u/k)\,du  \right |\le {2\over N}f(0)$$ Combining with the first formula gives $$ \lim_{k\to \infty}\int\limits_0^\infty {\sin u\over u}f(u/k)\,du =f(0)\int\limits_0^\infty {\sin u\over u}\,du    $$
